# Cross-Compile QT 6.2 for Raspberry-PI 4

Tags: qt, cmake, cross-compiling, qt6

so I have QT 6.2 source code, toolchain, and tools for cross-compiling source codes for raspberry, when I run the ./configure command like below:

```
../qt-everywhere-src-6.2.0/configure -qt-host-path /home/ahmad/Documents/projects/avapardaz/raspberry/out/ -release -opengl es2 -nomake examples -nomake tests -extprefix /home/ahmad/Documents/projects/avapardaz/raspberry/out/ -prefix /usr/local/qt6 -- -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/home/ahmad/Documents/projects/avapardaz/raspberry/toolchain.cmake   -DQT_BUILD_TOOLS_WHEN_CROSSCOMPILING=ON -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/home/ahmad/Qt5.15.1/6.2.0/gcc_64/lib/cmake/
```

cmake says:

```
Configuring 'qtbase'
CMake Error at qtbase/cmake/QtSetup.cmake:201 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt6HostInfo" with
  any of the following names:

    Qt6HostInfoConfig.cmake
    qt6hostinfo-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Qt6HostInfo" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Qt6HostInfo_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "Qt6HostInfo" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  qtbase/cmake/QtBuildInternals/QtBuildInternalsConfig.cmake:229 (include)
  qtbase/cmake/QtBuildInternals/QtBuildInternalsConfig.cmake:372 (qt_build_internals_set_up_private_api)
  qtbase/CMakeLists.txt:91 (qt_build_repo_begin)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/ahmad/Downloads/qt6-source/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
CMake Error at /home/ahmad/Downloads/qt6-source/qt-everywhere-src-6.2.0/qtbase/cmake/QtProcessConfigureArgs.cmake:947 (message):
  CMake exited with code 1.
```

also, I have a QT 6.2 working installation in: `/home/ahmad/Qt5.15.1/6.2.0/`

so how should I solve the problem with QtHostInfo?

thank you

Comment: Look at https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/configure-linux-device.html